# How to download Google AdWords reports automatically

Tags: api, reporting, ads, google-ads-api

Is it possible to programmatically download an AdWords report (containing information about campaign and keyword performance like impressions, clicks, CTR, etc.) without logging in to the AdWords web site?

I'm aware that they provide an API, but it appears that you have to be approved, and I don't need all the services -- just basic CSV report download.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Regard, that using API isn't for free, when you want to download Adwords reports. I've scripted such a solution on my own for logging into Google and downloading a prepared report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for as I know you could not programmatically download an AdWords report without login. But it is possible that you create script that automatically login in adwords accounts and then downloads all details. If you are loging in google adwords accounts then you can download. I have not much more idea abut script but my friend use this technique to save time.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to log into Adwords web site, you could try [Google AdWords Editor](http://www.google.com/intl/en/adwordseditor/) I personally haven't used it, but its worth a try to see if it can create reports.

If you have your own personal site Google may give you some "API Units" for free. And you could use their API to get your stats. The API has almost all the capability of what the Adwords site does, so its something to look into.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the reports section in adwords backend using firefox. Then press `<SHIFT>+<F4>` to open up the scratchpad. You would need to run this code. It would click the "Run Now" button one by one for each report. You can check the `innerHTML` of the `a` tags to see which range of indexes you really want to click on to get all the reports. You may want to change the 7000 milisecond delay also if needed. I changed my firefox settings to automatically save all filetypes of `*.csv` Give it some time maybe 2-5 minutes before it begins after clicking the OK from the "Start" dialog box.

```
function competitor_download(i){
 var competitor_tags = document.getElementsByTagName("a"); 
 //alert(i+"|"+competitor_tags[i].innerHTML);
 if(competitor_tags[i].innerHTML == "Run now"){
    competitor_tags[i].click();
 }
}

alert("Start");

for(i=15;i<260;i++){
var competitor_tags2 = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
 if(competitor_tags2[i].innerHTML == "Run now"){
  window.setTimeout(competitor_download,((i-15)*7000), i);
 }
}
```